# Reading Only the First Character of a Line with while loop

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char ch;
   int count;
   while ((ch = getchar()) != '#')
{
//if('\n' == ch)
//continue;
    printf("%c\n",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

for input like "abc/n"
With out if statment, it only print the first character and exit the while loop.
with the if statment, it also only print the first character and stay in the while loop.
why only print first letter? why exit the while loop even I didn't input'#'?

Comment: Posted code has `return 0;` within the loop body.

Comment: The posted code is invalid and won't even compile.

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char` for good reasons! The result does not fit into a `char` (unless both types have the same range).

Comment: " it only print the first character and exit the while loop" + `printf("%c\n",ch);
    return 0;` == makes sense, code prints and then exits.  Recommend to move `return` statement to outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getch` instead of `getchar` if you don't want displaying feedback to screen. But this is non-standard API.

Answer (score 0):

```
return 0;
```

Should be outside the while loop, plus you're missing the closing bracket of main function.